# how to insert arraylist into single column in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Sir i am pass array list through url android to php 
my `arraylistvalues[x,y.z,....]` this all values inserted into single column(menuname) in test table to mysql using php

i tried this

```
$a=$_POST['menuname'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","MobixMySQL");
mysql_select_db("test");
foreach($a as $value)
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES $value)")or
  die ('unable'.mysql_error());
  echo "Inserted";
}
```

i try above php it shows error valild argument in foreach please  tell me how to solve ..please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$a` might not be an array, and as such, `foreach` throws error as it expects its argument to be an array.

You can do a `var_dump` to see what `$_POST['menuname']` really is.

Also, use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape things before you insert to db

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')");
```

https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Or better yet, use `pdo`  http://sg.php.net/pdo

Comment: can u edit my code and post me. because i don't know php.. please

Comment: it is inserted one row in single column. if arraylist[x,y] means it should add x in one row y in one row in menuname column..please relplay

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`menuname`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string( $value )."')") or die ('unable'.mysql_error());
```